# How do I link to the Exception standard library class via intersphinx_mapping?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

My intersphinx_mapping doc looks like this:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python':('http://docs.python.org/2.7', None)}
```

In my code I have

```
:param Exception exc: the caught exception
```

I expect this to link to the exception docs in the standard library, but it doesn't. How come?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Exception` class is in the `exceptions` module, so change your code to this

```
:param exceptions.Exception exc: the caught exception
```